# How to run a MSC file extension using Regedit?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, process, context-menu, regedit

### scenario

I have an .msc file associated to a command of a personalized contextmeni item , which is stored in a reg value as a context menu option?.

This is the registry script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\CPanel.Administrador.de.discos]
@="Administrador de discos"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\CPanel.Administrador.de.discos\command]
@="devmgmt.msc"
```

---

### problem

When I click on the contexontextmenu item, absolutelly nothing happens.

[image]

---

### question

How to run an MSC file from registry?

Comment: MSC files are not regedit files; they are Microsoft Management Console Snap-in Control Files. This will not ever work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want something to happen when you right-click the MSC? Do you want the MSC to be an option in the context menu when you right-click another type of file, and if so, what type(s) of file(s)?

Comment: @krowe It has nothing to do to be a file "Reg" or not, I think you haven't understande me, my english is not very good, please see my update, thanks for comment,

Comment: @BillP3rd yes, the second option that you have said is more or less what I'm trying to do, the option will be at desktop background contextmenu, I've created the option, the only problem is the MSC file will not start like an exe file starts and I don't know what I need to do to fix the problem about trying to run an MSC file from a registry command value, thanks for comment!

Comment: So to be clear, you'd like the option to start DEVMGMT.MSC to appear as an option on the DESKTOP context menu. Is that correct? That's very straightforward, if so.

Comment: @BillP3rd More or less the answer is YES, A context menu option needs a reg key titled "command", in the Default value of the Command key you need to put the instruction to do (start a process) and that instruction is he thing that happens when you click the option, well, so I need to know how would be the Data of Default value of Command key to run a MSC file. If you can give me an example

Comment: I know how to rsolve the problem launching CMD to launch the MSC file, or Wscript host, or using a link, but I'm asking if I can do it in an improved way, maybe I need to add a command before the name of the MSC file to run it or something else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to run the *.MSC files as arguments to mmc like this:

```
 C:\Users\me>mmc C:\Windows\system32\devmgmt.msc
```

This doesn't work in your registry entries because they are not executables. Here is the updated regedit file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\CPanel.Administrador.de.discos]
@="Administrador de discos"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\CPanel.Administrador.de.discos\command]
@="mmc C:\Windows\system32\devmgmt.msc"
```

Comment: that's it, I didn't knew mmc can accept arguments, thankyou so much!

Comment: @krowe - Beat me to the answer. +1 for you!

Comment: with space > mmc "x:\xxx xxx\xxx.msc"